# None type error in Django rest RegisterView

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I am using Django RestFramework's RegisterView for the registration `API` in my project. I use a custom adapter as well, it is as follows.

```
class CustomAccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
"""
Override all_auth's default adapter
"""

def send_confirmation_mail(self, request, emailconfirmation, signup):
    # current_site = get_current_site(request)

    promo_code = emailconfirmation.email_address.user.promo_code
    activate_url = "%s/#/verifyEmail/%s/" % (
        settings.FRONTEND_HOSTNAME,
        emailconfirmation.key
    )
    if promo_code:
        activate_url = "%s/#/verifyEmail/%s/?promo_code=%s" % (
            settings.FRONTEND_HOSTNAME,
            emailconfirmation.key,
            promo_code
        )
    ctx = {
        "user": emailconfirmation.email_address.user,
        "activate_url": activate_url,
        "current_site": settings.FRONTEND_HOSTNAME
    }
    if signup:
        email_template = 'account/email/email_confirmation_signup'
    else:
        email_template = 'account/email/email_confirmation'

    self.send_mail(email_template,
                   emailconfirmation.email_address.email,
                   ctx)
```

I get an error while the sending the confirmation mail to the newly registered user.The error is below:

> File
>   "/home/ubuntu/fizprod_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py",
>   line 283, in send
>       return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])   File
>   "/home/ubuntu/fizprod_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py",
>   line 99, in send_messages
>       sent = self._send(message)   File "/home/ubuntu/fizprod_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py",
>   line 110, in _send
>       from_email = sanitize_address(email_message.from_email, email_message.encoding)   File
>   "/home/ubuntu/fizprod_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py",
>   line 105, in sanitize_address
>       nm, addr = addr TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Can anyone tell me what is the error and how it's happening? I use Django 1.7, Python 2.7, Django REST 3.1.1.

Comment: Can you post the rest of the traceback?

Comment: check your value of `emailconfirmation.email_address.email` , I think its value is `None` or something similar